# What are different between these ISO files?

Tags: linux, centos

What are different between these ISO files?

- `CentOS-Stream-8-20230509.0-x86_64-boot.iso` (955_252_736 bytes) (1)
- `CentOS-Stream-8-20230509.0-x86_64-dvd1.iso` (11_913_920_512 bytes) (2)
- `CentOS-Stream-8-x86_64-latest-boot.iso` (11_913_920_512 bytes) (3)

URL http://mirrors.nhanhoa.com/centos/8-stream/isos/x86_64/

I know that (2) is the same (3). If I have only 1 USB 8GB, can I use (1) only (without (2)) for installing?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The smaller image is a netinst image, i.e. just the installer that needs to download all packages from the internet at installation time; the DVD image is more complete and allows for an offline installation.

Personally, when deploying I use the netinst images, since I'd be doing a system update after installation anyways. But if you're a new user, use the DVD image, unless your stick is too small, then use the netinst image.